# Optimizing Python code iterating over millions of documents

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, performance, performance-testing

## **Context**

Hello I have a script that converts Mongo documents into JSON written to a file. To run the script on 1000 documents take approximately 45 seconds.

## **Predicament**

The Mongo collection however has nearly 18 million documents so it would take approximately 200 hours to go through the whole collection.

I am now looking to optimize the code to bring the time down significantly and was wondering what the options are to do so.

## **Possible Solutions**

I know there are hardware options such as running on a cluster with faster hard drives, but I was also wondering any optimizations I can do with the algorithm and other areas of the code.

Looking at the profiler, most of the time is spend in 
`{method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}` (Not sure what this does) and `encoder.py:212(iterencode)` (Converting to JSON). These are built in functions, but the rest of the time consuming functions are user defined.

Some possible solutions I am considering are: 1. Copying a list of strings using writeline 2. Compiling to C code using a package like Cython 3. Using faster data structures and algorithmic process.

As for 3. I'm not sure how I can implement a faster algorithm as I have to go through nested layers for each document to create the entries.

Specifically for each document, there are subdocuments indicated by the key 'd'. Each subdocument also has keys that being with 'AT' such as 'AT432'. I have to create an individual entry for each 'AT' so one document can result in 50 individual entries.

## **Help Welcome!**

I'm open to any ideas as I would really like to reduce the time spent converting each document. Thanks for your input!

File 1

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import cProfile
import sys
import time
from mapping_functions import create_files
from datetime import datetime
from date_functions import get_array_of_dates

pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

start_time = time.time()

# A. Connect to a collection in MongoDB
client = MongoClient('mongo-host-ip', 27017)
db = client.db_name
collection = db.collection_name

# Set time range for query in year, month, day, hour
start = datetime(2017, 12, 29, 10)
end = datetime(2017, 12, 29, 11)
delta_in_minutes = 60

num_documents = 1000
dates = get_array_of_dates(start, end, delta_in_minutes)

create_files(collection, 'collection_name', dates, start_time, num_documents)
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats(sort='time')
```

File 2

```
import dateutil.parser
import calendar
import datetime
import time
import json
from bson import json_util
import os


# creates new folder
def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' + directory)


# creates a file with the entries for each hour
def create_files(collection_cursor, collection_name, dates, start_time, 
                 num_documents):
    createFolder('./data_hour/' + collection_name + '/')
    for string_time in dates:
        python_datetime = dateutil.parser.parse(string_time)
        documents = collection_cursor.find({'T': python_datetime}).limit(num_documents)
        text_file = open('./data_hour/' + collection_name + '/' + string_time +
                         ".json", "a")
        document_parser(collection_name, documents, text_file)
        text_file.close()


# exports sql entries to a file
def document_parser(collection_name, documents, text_file):
    list = []
    for doc in documents:
        list_of_subdocuments = subdocument_parser(doc['d'])
        for subdoc in list_of_subdocuments:
            actiontypes = actiontype_parser(subdoc)
            for actiontype in actiontypes:
                sql_entry = nosql_to_sql(collection_name, doc, subdoc,
                                         actiontype)
                text_file.write(json.dumps(sql_entry,
                                           separators=(',', ':'),
                                           default=json_util.default) + '\n')
    return


# returns a list of subdocuments
def subdocument_parser(subdocuments):
    subdocs = []

    for subdoc in subdocuments:
        subdocs.append(subdoc)
    return subdocs


# returns a list of action types
def actiontype_parser(subdocument):
    actiontypes = []

    # Find all of the keys that represent action types
    keys = subdocument.keys()
    for key in keys:
        if key[:2] == 'AT':
            actiontypes.append(key)
    return actiontypes


def handle_arrays(json, document, key, full_key):
    sorted_array = sorted(document[key])
    comma_separated_string = ','.join(map(str, sorted_array))
    json[full_key] = comma_separated_string
    return


def handle_time(json, document, key, full_key):
    epoch = document[key]
    seconds = calendar.timegm(epoch.utctimetuple())
    json[full_key] = seconds
    return


# Copy all keys in the document except 'd'
def copy_document_keys(json, mapping, collection_name, document,
                       document_keys):
    for key in document_keys:
        if key in prohibited:
            continue
        if key != 'd':
            full_key = mapping[key]
            # sort array and convert to csv
            if key == 'MP' and collection_name in inventory_or_auction:
                full_key += 's'
                handle_arrays(json, document, key, full_key)
                continue
            if key == 'T':
                handle_time(json, document, key, full_key)
                continue
            json[full_key] = document[key]
    return


# Copy all the keys in a subdocument except for action types
def copy_subdocument_keys(json, mapping, subdocument, subdocument_keys):
    for key in subdocument_keys:
        if key in prohibited:
            continue
        if key[:2] != 'AT':
            full_key = mapping[key]
            # sort array and convert to csv
            if key == 'UI' or key == 'DA' or key == 'F':
                handle_arrays(json, subdocument, key, full_key)
                continue
            json[full_key] = subdocument[key]
    return


# copy misc. keys
def copy_misc_keys(json, subdocument, actiontype):
    # If there is no recordType key, then put default value
    if 'recordType' not in json:
        json['recordType'] = 1

    # Copy the action type
    json['actionType'] = int(actiontype[2:])
    json['count'] = int(subdocument[actiontype])
    return


# return a sql entry
def nosql_to_sql(collection_name, document, subdocument, actiontype):
    json = {}

    # Copy all keys in the document except 'd'
    document_keys = document.keys()
    copy_document_keys(json, mapping, collection_name, document, document_keys)

    # Copy all the keys in a subdocument except for action types
    subdocument_keys = subdocument.keys()
    copy_subdocument_keys(json, mapping, subdocument, subdocument_keys)

    # copy action types
    copy_misc_keys(json, subdocument, actiontype)

    return json
```

Mongo Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("7dfgdftew564324546ff3"),
    "T" : ISODate("2011-10-13T07:00:00Z"),
    "MP" : [
        40,
        16,
        13,
        11,
        1
    ],
    "P" : 3881,
    "PB" : 12285,
    "d" : [
        {
            "D" : 32,
            "DL" : 0,
            "ST" : 1007,
            "AT315" : NumberLong(5),
            "AT328" : NumberLong(14),
            "AT331" : NumberLong(19),
            "AT306" : NumberLong(19),
            "AT100331" : NumberLong(431),
            "AT500" : 0
        },
        {
            "D" : 16,
            "DL" : 0,
            "ST" : 1007,
            "AT328" : NumberLong(28),
            "AT315" : NumberLong(8),
            "AT331" : NumberLong(36),
            "AT306" : NumberLong(36),
            "AT100331" : NumberLong(953),
            "AT500" : 0
        },
        {
            "D" : 1,
            "DL" : 0,
            "ST" : 1007,
            "AT315" : NumberLong(29),
            "AT331" : NumberLong(34),
            "AT328" : NumberLong(5),
            "AT306" : NumberLong(34),
            "AT100331" : NumberLong(803),
            "AT500" : 0
        },
        {
            "D" : 2,
            "DL" : 0,
            "ST" : 1007,
            "AT328" : NumberLong(1),
            "AT100331" : NumberLong(82),
            "AT306" : NumberLong(1),
            "AT331" : NumberLong(1),
            "AT500" : 0
        }
    ],
    "bn" : NumberLong(21137)
}
```

Resulting entries written to a file

```
   {"count":254,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":100331,"recordType":1}
{"count":7,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":306,"recordType":1}
{"count":7,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":331,"recordType":1}
{"count":6,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":315,"recordType":1}
{"count":1,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":328,"recordType":1}
{"count":0,"publisher":730,"marketPlaces":"1,13","publication":6452,"deal":0,"hour":1514541600,"deviceType":1,"provider":1011,"actionType":500,"recordType":1} ...
```

Result from profiling

```
         30567605 function calls (30567594 primitive calls) in 48.483 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     5476    6.992    0.001    6.992    0.001 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
  1194719    5.489    0.000    5.489    0.000 encoder.py:212(iterencode)
  1194719    4.869    0.000    4.869    0.000 mapping_functions.py:180(copy_subdocument_keys)
  1194719    4.254    0.000   11.878    0.000 mapping_functions.py:160(copy_document_keys)
  1194719    3.223    0.000   13.123    0.000 __init__.py:193(dumps)
        2    3.175    1.587   48.480   24.240 mapping_functions.py:99(document_parser)
  1194719    2.032    0.000    2.032    0.000 mapping_functions.py:195(copy_misc_keys)
  1194719    1.810    0.000   21.245    0.000 mapping_functions.py:207(nosql_to_sql)
  1194719    1.726    0.000    8.666    0.000 encoder.py:186(encode)
        6    1.606    0.268    1.611    0.268 {bson._cbson.decode_all}
  1194719    1.438    0.000    1.438    0.000 {method 'utctimetuple' of 'datetime.datetime' objects}
  1194719    1.320    0.000    1.438    0.000 calendar.py:611(timegm)
  1194719    1.261    0.000    3.619    0.000 mapping_functions.py:145(handle_arrays)
  1194719    1.234    0.000    1.234    0.000 encoder.py:101(__init__)
  1194720    1.227    0.000    1.227    0.000 {map}
  1194719    1.130    0.000    4.006    0.000 mapping_functions.py:152(handle_time)
  2389438    1.025    0.000    1.025    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
  1194719    0.929    0.000    0.929    0.000 {sorted}
  1194719    0.818    0.000    0.818    0.000 {method 'write' of 'file' objects}
  2555978    0.718    0.000    0.718    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
  2391505    0.628    0.000    0.628    0.000 {isinstance}
   166540    0.573    0.000    0.788    0.000 mapping_functions.py:134(actiontype_parser)
  2558008    0.339    0.000    0.339    0.000 {time.time}
  1361313    0.165    0.000    0.165    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        7    0.123    0.018    0.123    0.018 {time.sleep}
       12    0.121    0.010    7.118    0.593 network.py:166(_receive_data_on_socket)
  1194719    0.118    0.000    0.118    0.000 {method 'toordinal' of 'datetime.date' objects}
     2000    0.037    0.000    0.050    0.000 mapping_functions.py:125(subdocument_parser)
        1    0.035    0.035    0.035    0.035 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
        6    0.030    0.005    0.031    0.005 message.py:953(unpack)
     2002    0.010    0.000    8.942    0.004 cursor.py:1165(next)
     9567    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {len}
     2000    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 database.py:402(_fix_outgoing)
     2001    0.004    0.000    0.005    0.000 objectid.py:68(__init__)
        6    0.002    0.000    7.151    1.192 network.py:143(receive_message)
        7    0.001    0.000    8.926    1.275 cursor.py:1057(_refresh)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {_socket.getaddrinfo}
     2022    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 collection.py:306(database)
        2    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'close' of 'file' objects}
```

Comment: That `{method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}` is [`socket.recv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)—in other words, reading data off a network connection. The socket in question is probably the connection to your database; if so, optimizing any part but the database queries will be wasted time. That may just mean running requests in parallel (e.g., with a mess of threads), and/or doing smaller or larger batches. Or it may require rethinking the process at a higher level so you don't need all those heavy db requests.

Comment: Following up on what @abarnert said, could you just run your query with `mongoexport` to obtain a dump of all the data you need, and only then perform the conversion?

Comment: If the Python code is executed on the same machine as the MongoDB server, maybe try using a Unix socket DB connection? Lots of overhead in TCP/IP...

Comment: @abarnert So if I'm understanding correctly, the bottleneck is the latency in sending the information of each document through the network?

Comment: @Pierre Do you think it'd be faster to read the dump from a file rather than iterating through the documents from the cursor?

Comment: @abarnert What about the algorithm itself? Do you see any ways to improve it?

Comment: It isn't worth wasting time trying to improve something that's taking a tiny minority of your total time. Assume we're reading the profiling right, the first thing to improve is your DB query. The second thing appears to be something to do with encoding the output—probably either the JSON encoding, or the UTF-8 encoding done as part of that, which probably means using a faster JSON encoder, unless you can redesign things to not write as much. Next appears to be parsing the query results. If you can optimize all of that to where your algorithm is a good chunk of what's left, worry about it.